# How to include section numbers in the eLife template of Overleaf?

Tags: sectioning, overleaf

I would like to use the [eLife template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/elife-latex-template/csqxykvsnyxm) in Overleaf for the supplementary material. Since it is very long, I need to include section numbers, to make it easier for the reader to navigate the document.

In the cls file, the set up for the sectioning includes the command:

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
```

which I have changed to

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
```

This includes the numbers to the section, but there is no spacing between the section number and the section title (so it looks ugly, see image)

[image]

and I also get two types of errors when I compile:

```
Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   !
l.123 ...m when used on the co-infection data set}

A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)
```

and

```
Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
<to be read again> 
                   !
l.123 ...m when used on the co-infection data set}

Dimensions can be in units of em, ex, in, pt, pc,
cm, mm, dd, cc, nd, nc, bp, or sp; but yours is a new one!
I'll assume that you meant to say pt, for printer's points.
To recover gracefully from this error, it's best to
delete the erroneous units; e.g., type `2' to delete
two letters. (See Chapter 27 of The TeXbook.)
```

I only know enough about how to use latex to write a document, but I am not able to change the formatting and the look of it. So any guidance on how I can edit the cls file to stop the errors and improve the look would be helpful.

To open the eLife template in overleaf and have a look at the source code, you can follow this [link](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/elife-latex-template/csqxykvsnyxm).

Many thanks!

Comment: In `eLife.cls` file search for `\titleformat` commands and add a distance value on fourth mandatori parameter which is empty.

Comment: @Ignasi Would you like to add an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`eLife.cls` associated to [`eLife` template in Overleaf](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/elife-latex-template/csqxykvsnyxm) shows following lines:

```
%
% section/subsection/paragraph set-up
%
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\RequirePackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\color{eLifeMediumGrey}\Large\bfseries}
  {\thesection}{}{#1}[]
\titleformat{\subsection}
  {\large\bfseries}
  {\thesubsection}{}{#1}[]
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
  {\large}
  {\thesubsubsection}{}{#1}[]    
\titleformat{\paragraph}
  {\color{eLifeMediumGrey}\large}
  {\theparagraph}{}{#1}[] 
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pc}{3ex \@plus4pt \@minus3pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pc}{2.5ex \@plus3pt \@minus2pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsection}{0pc}{2ex \@plus2.5pt \@minus1.5pt}{0pt}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}{0pc}{1.5ex \@plus2pt \@minus1pt}{0pt}
```

According to [`titlesec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) documentation, the fourth parameter in `\titleformat` command is the distance between section number and title. As `eLife` declares `titleformat` commands with empty distance, even increasing `secnumdepth` the distance will be 0.

You'll have to insert some distance in fourth parameter in all these `\titleformat` commands. Just an example:

```
\titleformat{\section}
  {\color{eLifeMediumGrey}\Large\bfseries}
  {\thesection}{0.5em}{#1}[]
```